# UIKit UISwipeGestureRecognizer in Xcode crashes app during nib loading?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I've added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to my Xcode nib and having it there makes my app crash with:

> ..exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UISwipeGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x5c2ab30'.

Why?

Comment: Are you running it on the wrong version of iOS?

Comment: @jtbandes: ugh yes. I'm using 5.0 sdk and was using 4.3.x simulator.  That's unfortunate.. why would this issue exist?  How should I address it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is happening because you're running the app on the wrong version of iOS. You can't put gesture recognizers in a xib file on iOS <5, so you'll have to create them in code if you want to support older versions of iOS.